# How can I change a template message depending on if a variable is null or not?

Tags: angularjs

I am using this message:

```
{{ qs.q.hint }}
```

How can I make it so the message displays "Please choose the correct answers" if qs.q.hint is null or "" ?

Comment: You can always mark an answer as accepted when it resolved your problem

Answer (score 4):

Very simple with the `ng-show` or `ng-hide` directives:

```
<span ng-hide="qs.q.hint">Please choose the correct answer</span>
```

If the expression referred to by `qs.q.hint` is truthy (not `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `false` or the empty string), it will hide the span. The reverse can be achieved with `ng-show` or using the unary `!` boolean operator.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend this:

```
{{ qs.q.hint || "Please choose the correct answers" }}
```

This watches the `$scope.qs.q.hint` and as soon as it is not undefined or null, the message will change

It is also the most concise. You can also chain multiple values to this kind of expression, and the first truthy value will be returned. For example, you might have qs.q.hint return a string hint when a user clicks 'show me hint'. But you might also want a different hypothetical function to return an explanation if they selected an incorrect answer. Then you could do this, if you had a function `selectedValInfo()` that returned undefined, false, 0, or null until a value is selected, then some information is returned. This would be overridden when qs.q.hint becomes truthy.

```
{{ qs.q.hint || qs.q.selectedValInfo() || "Please choose the correct answers" }}
```

Comment: Note: this also relies on the fact that the logical javascript OR operator _returns_ the first truthy value found. (Something that is odd for someone like me who is coming from a more traditional programming language like Java)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use angular [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) as same as regular `if condition`

```
  <span ng-if="qs.q.hint===null || qs.q.hint===''">Please choose the correct answer</span>

  <span ng-if="qs.q.hint!==null || qs.q.hint!==''">qs.q.hint</span>
```